# How to replace content of div element?

Tags: javascript, html, byte-order-mark

i want to add more than one element to my content it should be (h1,input and some buttons). So i wrote a function where i created h1 and input and now i try to add it to my div content and got an error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined).
Here is my code:

```
let el = document.getElementById('add');
if (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        let rootDiv = document.getElementById('content');
        rootDiv.innerHTML = addElement();
    })
}

function addElement() {
    let h = document.createElement("H1");
    let t = document.createTextNode("Add task");
    h.appendChild(t);
    let input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    document.rootDiv.appendChild(h);
    document.rootDiv.appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: `rootDiv.innerHTML = addElement();` makes no sense. `addElement` does not return anything, so you are setting rootDiv to undefined.

Comment: where is the element with id add?

Comment: This won't work `document.rootDiv.appendChild` ... should be something like `rootDiv.appendChild`

Comment: `rootDiv` is not a global variable. You'll have to pass it to the function.

Comment: rootDiv is not available as its let hence block scope?

Comment: `let rootDiv = document.getElementById('content');` this exists only inside your click handler function. Also, your `addElement` function doesn't return anything (thus returning what all functions return by default, which is `undefined`), so it does not make sense to assign that to `rootDiv.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such `document.rootDiv` on which you can implement `appenChild()`.

You can append the child directly to the container element. You do not need to set the `innerHTML`. Simply call the function.

To clear the existing content, you can use 
`element.innerHTML = ""` before appending the childs.

```js
let el = document.getElementById('add');;
if (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    addElement();
  });
}

function addElement() {
  let rootDiv = document.getElementById('content')
  rootDiv.innerHTML = "";
  let h = document.createElement("H1");
  let t = document.createTextNode("Add task");
  h.appendChild(t);
  let input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  rootDiv.appendChild(h);
  rootDiv.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="content"> <h1>Simple TODO application</h1> <a href="#addNewItem"><button id="add">Add new task</button></a> <p>TODO is empty</p> <h1></h1> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let el = document.getElementById('add');
if (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let rootDiv = document.getElementById('content');
    addElement(rootDiv);
  })
}

function addElement(rootDiv) {
  let h = document.createElement("H1");
  let t = document.createTextNode("Add task");
  h.appendChild(t);
  let input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  rootDiv.appendChild(h);
  rootDiv.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="add" value="Submit" />

<div id="content"></div>
```

If you need to continuosly replace content with new one instead of adding, you may add another function for clearing container before `addElement`.
Check this snippet:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('add');
if (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let rootDiv = document.getElementById('content');
    clearDiv(rootDiv); // clear container before pasting new content
    addElement(rootDiv);
  })
}

function addElement(rootDiv) {
  let h = document.createElement("H1");
  let t = document.createTextNode("Add task");
  h.appendChild(t);
  let input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  rootDiv.appendChild(h);
  rootDiv.appendChild(input);
}

function clearDiv(div) { // function for clearing rootDiv
    while (div.firstChild) {
        div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="add" value="Submit" />

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Yeap, it works thanks. But it adds down a new content to my current and i need to change my current content to the new one.

Comment: So you need to always replace `h1` and `input` with new?

Comment: here is my HTML: 
`  <div id="content">
    <h1>Simple TODO application</h1>
    <a href="#addNewItem"><button id="add">Add new task</button></a>
    <p>TODO is empty</p>
    <h1></h1>
  </div>`


And when i click on button this content should disappear and the new one should replace it.